# bytes(HOST) raises "string argument without an encoding"

Tags: python, sockets, udp

i am trying to play around with python 3.5 using udp comunication but i cant seem to ever get the socket library to work it always give this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Nicholas Hendricks\Desktop\udpServer.py", line 8, in  <module>
   bytes(HOST)
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

and here is my Code:

```
import socket
import time

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT =  5454
data = "sup bruh"

bytes(HOST)
bytes(PORT)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


while 1:
    s.sendto(data,(HOST,PORT))
    print ("sent:" + data)
```

Comment: `b = bytes(HOST, 'utf-8')`

Comment: You don't have to paste the trace back in the title, a summarization would be better. The content is searchable on the Internet as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `bytes()` assumes a encoding argument like so:

```
HOST = bytes(HOST, 'utf-8')
```

But I don't see why you convert port to bytes, I'm on the phone so can't check but isn't it supposed to be a integer?

And you will probably want to convert data as well:

```
data = bytes(data, 'utf-8')
```